# Solidity - string contains

Tags: solidity

In my requirement I have list of whitelist domains(xyz.com, abc.com etc.) and I have to write smart contract to check the data is coming from one of our whitelisted domains...

**Solution number one:** Store comma separated whitelisted domains in a string and then 
use a library like [stringutils](https://github.com/Arachnid/solidity-stringutils#containsslice-self-slice-needle-internal-returns-bool) or [solidity-util](https://github.com/willitscale/solidity-util) and check if my newdomain is available in my whitelisted domains.

**Solution number two:** Store whitelisted domains in string[] and loop through the array and if my newdomain is available in my whitelisted domains array.

I am wondering which solution is better for my scenario?

Also there is one more problem, how can I validate data like http://xyz.com, www.xyz.com, xyz.com etc all of them are valid domains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution number three:**

- Store whitelisted domains in `mapping (string => bool) whitelisted`
- Find out if a given `domain` is whitelisted, using `if (whitelisted[domain])`